# Mysql TIMESTAMPDIFF for time datatype return negative value

Tags: mysql

Here are my query

```
SELECT r.*,TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,r.from, r.to) / 60 as hours from RestaurantOpeningHours r;
```

here are the result :

```
id     rId day  from        to          createdAt           updatedAt           hours
142054  1   1   11:00:00    14:00:00    2020-09-07 19:52:30 2020-09-07 19:52:30 3.0000
142055  1   2   13:15:00    03:15:00    2020-09-07 19:52:30 2020-09-07 19:52:30 -10.0000
```

expected result :

```
id     rId day  from        to          createdAt           updatedAt           hours
142054  1   1   11:00:00    14:00:00    2020-09-07 19:52:30 2020-09-07 19:52:30 3.0000
142055  1   2   13:15:00    03:15:00    2020-09-07 19:52:30 2020-09-07 19:52:30 14.0000
```

since from `13:15:00` to `03:15:00` are 14 hours of difference. Always assume that value on `to` field are in the future.
`from` and `to` field are `time` data type

What is the correct query that will return my expected result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not really clear what your schema is and what is the meaning of `day` field.
But to get what you want you just need to take `day` into consideration:

```
SELECT
    r.*, TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, r.from, r.to  + INTERVAL (CASE WHEN r.to < r.from THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DAY) AS hours
FROM
    RestaurantOpeningHours r
;
```

Which gives what you want:

```
id      rId day from        to          createdAt               updatedAt               hours
142054  1   1   11:00:00    14:00:00    2020-09-07T19:52:30Z    2020-09-07T19:52:30Z    3
142055  1   2   13:15:00    03:15:00    2020-09-07T19:52:30Z    2020-09-07T19:52:30Z    14
```

I've changed `hours` calculation and removed getting hours from minutes by changing first parameter of `TIMESTAMPDIFF` and removing division by 60.

It also would be greate if you've propvided some creation and filling scripts.

Here are mine:

```
CREATE TABLE RestaurantOpeningHours(
  `id` INT PRIMARY KEY,
  `rId` INT,
  `day` INT,
  `from` TIME,
  `to` TIME,
  `createdAt` TIMESTAMP,
  `updatedAt` TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO RestaurantOpeningHours VALUES
  (142054, 1, 1, "11:00:00", "14:00:00", "2020-09-07 19:52:30", "2020-09-07 19:52:30"),
  (142055, 1, 2, "13:15:00", "03:15:00", "2020-09-07 19:52:30", "2020-09-07 19:52:30")
;
```

Comment: day is name of day in `integer`, sunday is 1, and monday is 7 ..

Comment: I've made a change in `SELCELC` query. Now it just adds one day if `to` is less then `from`, If I get you right, there is no need in counting for `day` at all. This is just a day of week.

Answer (score 1):

Mysql TIMESTAMPDIFF function works like this.

TIMESTAMPDIFF(unit,datetime_expr1,datetime_expr2);
[image]

What is Interval value?
MySQL interval values are used mainly for date and time calculations. To create
an interval value, you use the following expression,

(INTERVAL expr unit)
ex: INTERVAL 1 DAY

finally I used if function.

I hope this code may help you to solve your problem.

```
SELECT
    r.*, TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, r.from, r.to  + Interval if(r.from<r.to,0,1) day) AS hours
FROM
    RestaurantOpeningHours r
;
```